# Parse query using loop

Tags: java, android, loops, parse-platform

I'm working on a survey application.the application has a dynamic number of questions and a specific survey code number.

I am trying to use a query to get all the questions matching the survey code number and add them to a list array.
Currently i am trying to use a while loop to do the job but i am getting an error.

here is the code snippet:

```
//This query is to count the number of Questions that match the surveyCode
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Field");
query.whereEqualTo("codeField", value);
query.countInBackground(new CountCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(int count, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            //The query succeeded
            countQeus = count;
            //This loop is to get the question and put them into list Array
            while(i<countQeus)
            {
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Field");
                query.whereEqualTo("codeField", value);
                query.whereEqualTo("quesNumber", i + 1);//i = 0
                query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            question = list.toString();
                            list11.add(i, question.toString());
                            //Log.i("Question is:  ",list11.get(i));
                        }
                    }
                });
                i++;
            }
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

If there is another way to do it without using a loop, i am open for suggestions.
Thanks,

Comment: Its really hard to suggest a better solution without knowing how your data is organized.  Ideally you want a one to many relation between the survey code and questions.  That way you can just fetch all the question associated with a specific survey code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply,
Here is a screen shot of my database and the fields that are in it:
http://s22.postimg.org/6o9cqe6tt/Capture.jpg

How do I apply the one to many relation you suggested?